# Why is my constructor involving a shared_ptr incorrect?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a class, which uses a shared_ptr as a member variable, which I want to initialize to a nullptr. Why is this incorrect? The compiler error message is: "delete: cannot delete objects, that are not pointers".

```
template<class T>
class Example:
public: 
    Example() : myptr(make_shared<Example<T>>), val(0) {}

private:
    shared_ptr<Example<T>> myptr;
    T val;
```

I thought that this would create my shared_ptr and it would initialize it to a nullptr.

Also what would the correct constructor look like?

Comment: How would you use `make_shared` outside of a constructor?

Comment: On an unrelated note: What if the type `T` doesn't have a constructor that takes an integer as its only argument? If you want to default-construct `val` then use val()`.

Comment: Just initialize myptr to nullptr without the make_shared. 
`Example() : myptr{nullptr}, val{} { }`
?
In actuality just declaring the shared_ptr would set it to null by default !

Comment: `make_shared<Example<T>>` is a function. You have to call the function (`make_shared<Example<T>>()`), but as @nitimalh pointed out this isn't necessary. And one more step up, what nitimalh recommends isn't necessary. The default constructor will take care of it for you. [See note 1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Comment: Replace `myptr(make_shared<Example<T>>)` with `myptr()`.

Comment: Your constructor says that when someone creates an `Example<T>`, you want to make a shared `Example<T>` as well. But making that shared `Example<T>` will invoke the default constructor recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_shared<Example<T>>` is a function, not a function call. Initialising a `shared_ptr` to a function doesn't make sense. The error you're getting is because `shared_ptr` attempts to delete the function when the `shared_ptr` gets destroyed, but functions cannot be deleted.

> which I want to initialize to a nullptr

Then you don't want `make_shared` at all. Just initialise it to `nullptr`. (Or, as pointed out in comments, omit the initialisation entirely, since `nullptr` is the default value of a `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: ok, this makes sense

So I should only use the make_shared function when I actually assign the pointer to something?

Comment: @Á.Márton `make_shared` is for when you want to create an object, and a `shared_ptr` referring to that object, at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a class, which uses a shared_ptr as a member variable, which I
>   want to initialize to a nullptr.

Great, Do nothing. the default constructor of `std::shared_ptr` anyway nullifies  the pointer. you don't need to do anything.

> `Example() : myptr(make_shared<Example<T>>), val(0) {}`

First of all, if you call `make_shared` then you can be sure that your assigned `shared_ptr` **will not** be null, you are assigning a newly constructed managed object! it's like calling `new` and wrapping it with a shared pointer , it won't nullify the object.

but if you do want to call `make_shared`, you need to add parentheses as in regular function call:

```
 myptr(make_shared<Example<T>>(/*arguments*/))
```